# UISearchController appearance troubles

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, uiappearance

I'm currently developing an app with a search functionally, for that I use an UISearchController. The searchBar of the UISearchController is display within the NavigationItem.

The problem is that when a search is done, it's possible to click on an item to display details in an UITableViewController. In this UITableViewController, I make the NavigationBar transparent, but when the view is dismissed, I have troubles with the searchBar and statusBar appearance even if I reset the NavigationBar in the viewWillAppear method in the UITableViewController which display the UISearchController.

```swift
// Extension to make the NavigationBar transparent or as "default"
extension UINavigationBar {

    func setTransparent() {
        setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        isTranslucent = true
        shadowImage = UIImage()
    }

    func setDefault() {
        setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
        isTranslucent = true
        shadowImage = nil
    }
}
```

```swift
// I set the bar as "default" when the SearchController appear
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setDefault()
}
```

```swift
// I set the bar as transparent when the TableViewController is pushing
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setTransparent()
}
```

[Because a video is better than words !](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zMV1yZHxqB_zFiqrYy6p7bpo6jNbOgoh/view?usp=sharing)

I don't know if it is an iOS bug, but I looking for app which has the same behavior I expect and I found that the Apple TV app does exactly the same but in TV app this work perfectly.

[Video here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14L0VFnqLXqrfLii5eUmppDjTyk6w27te/view?usp=sharing)

How can I do the same behavior?

Comment: I have one suggestion if possible replace `UIViewController` with `UITableViewController`. May be that way you can workaround for now.

Comment: @Kampai could you briefly explain why that would solve the problem?

Comment: @AuRis: It is a suggestion, `UISearchController` works perfect with `UITableViewController`, I always uses `UISearchController` with `UITableViewController `, that is why I suggest to use it. If it does solve the problem of that glitch.

Comment: @Kampai: The controller which display the UISearchController is already an UITableViewController.

Comment: @Jean-CharlesNeboit: Yes, that is already we know. Instead of defending on my comments give it a try. Again guys this is not an answer, this is a comment.